# TFS2010 - Wrong changeset appearing at SourceGetVersion

Tags: tfs, build-process

I am currently setting up a Team Foundation Server 2010 and I found a very strange behavior when performing a build:

The situation explained:
We have 2 Branches

- Development
- Main

All developers check in code into the Development branch only. Once per day, the build manager merges some changesets over to the Main branch. On the Development brach, a continuous build at each check in is running. On the Main branch, once per day (in the night) a build is triggered.

Now suppose that the changesets 1-100 are being merged into the Main brach at 5pm, giving changeset 101 as the merge operation. Some developers check in changesets 102-106 after 5 o'clock into the Development branch. Now at 11pm the daily build is automatically triggered and runs on the Main branch. The last changeset of the Main branch is changeset 101. However, the Build details shows changeset 106:

[image]

I could imagine that this behavior is intended, because if you check out changeset 106 on the Main branch, you will in fact get the content of changeset 101. But it would be much more readable if this Build summary showed the correct number.

Question 1: Is there a way of manipulating the ouput of the SourceGetVersion information? Maybe through the Build Process Template?

The second scenario, where the TFS behaves strange is even worse:
When queuing a new build, there is the option of entering the "Get Version" Parameter, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

If I now click on "queue", the build is triggered and AGAIN the build detail outputs the changeset 106 although I specifically set it to get changeset 76.

Question 2: Is this a bug? Is there a hotfix or something to fix this? Or is there any option flag that has to be set?

I hope someone knows more about this. I don't really believe that this is a bug, because it is such a vital functionality that other people must have encountered it before.

Thanks for any help!! 
Christian

**EDIT 1**

The folder structure of the Team Project is:

$ProjectName

- BuildProcessTemplates
- Documentation
- SourceCode

  - Development <-- this is a branch

    - 3rdParty
    - Source
  - Main <-- this is a branch

    - 3rdParty
    - Source

The build only pulls the Main branch and everything below it.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a picture of the Workspace tab in the build definition:
[image]

Comment: 1) Can you give more details about "manipulating the SourceGetVersion property"? What do you want to do?

2) I don't have access to the source code at the moment to see what happened in this scenario, but does the build get the right version and show the "wrong" changeset number, or the build get the wrong version?

Comment: @DuatLe - By manipulating I mean to change the number it outputs, i.e. replace the "triggered Copy of ... for changeset 106" by "... for changeset 101". The sourcecode it actually downloads seems to be correct. It is just showing the wrong one. Inside the database on the TFS server, it also stores the wrong changeset information.

Comment: Is your build pulling only the Main branch from source control or Main and Development?

Comment: @RyanRinaldi - The build is pulling only the main branch. I will edit my question and add the folder structure.

Comment: At the moment, I do not have access to the TFS. Tomorrow morning I will add a picture of the BuildDefinition settings.

Comment: I've been able to repro this issue with TFS 2013.  I've created a [Microsoft Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/856643/ibuilddetail-sourcegetversion-returns-incorrect-changeset).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally I found out what is going on:

Basically The changeset that can be seen in my picture 1 is always the latest changeset of the entire **Team Project Collection**. It is the property "SourceGetVersion" on the object "BuildDetails" of type "IBuildDetails".

I think this is a bug which can be worked around:
If you change the BuildDetails.SourceGetVersion (which is a string) to some other value, then the build summary will show the updated string. Furthermore, it is then saved correctly to the collection database.

What I have done in order to add the correct changeset number is I have created a custom build activity that takes the branch which should be build as input parameter. It outputs the correct changeset. The activity finds out the correct changeset by connecting to the TFS and downloading the History. Then it looks at all the items in the history and outputs the largest changeset number. Here is the code of that activity:

```
using System.Activities;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;

namespace SourceGetVersionActivity
{
    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
    public sealed class SourceGetVersionActivity : CodeActivity<string>
    {
        // Define an activity input argument of type string
        public InArgument<string> Branch { get; set; }

        // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
        // and return the value from the Execute method.
        protected override string Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
            string branch = context.GetValue(this.Branch);

            ICredentials account = new NetworkCredential("Useranme", "password", "domain");

            // connect / authenticate with tfs
            TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfs:8080/tfs/CollectionName", account);
            tfs.Authenticate();

            // get the version control service
            VersionControlServer versionControl = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

            IEnumerable changesets = versionControl.QueryHistory(branch, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full,
                null, null, null, int.MaxValue, false, false, false, false);

            int maxVersion = 0;

            foreach (Changeset c in changesets)
            {
                if (c.ChangesetId > maxVersion)
                {
                    maxVersion = c.ChangesetId;
                }
            }

            return string.Concat('C', maxVersion.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I call this activity as soon as possible (after the GetBuild activity).

Basically in the BuildProcessTemplate I have added an Argument (string) "Branch" which needs to be filled with a string that points to the top folder that is being build. The custom activity takes that as input and outputs a string which is the correct changeset id. The BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion property will then be overriden by the correct changeset id.

I find it really strange that no-one else seems to have encountered this problem. I could not find any person on the internet with the same problem. Anyway, I hope this answer helps someone else in the future as well.

**EDIT - Writing the above code directly in Workflow Foundation:**

To get the correct changeset using more compact code and avoiding custom activites, it is also possible to use Workflow Foundation directly. Below is the "code" (doing exactly what is done in above C# code):

[image]

(1) The GetTeamProjectCollection activity gets the current collection. I am saving it inside the *TeamProjectCollection* variable (see bottom of the picture). Important: The variable needs to be defined inside this sequence, if you define it in outer scope, an error will occur: "Unable to serialize type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection'.  Verify that the type is public and either has a default constructor or an instance descriptor."

(2) Foreach "changeset" in "TeamProjectCollection.GetService(Of VersionControlServer).QueryHistory(Branch, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Integer.MaxValue, False, False, False).Cast(Of Changeset)()"
The TypeArgument of the Foreach loop is "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset".
This expression gets the version control object from the collection, calls it "QueryHistory" method which returns an IEnumerable with all changesets.

(3) So we are iterating over all changesets and looking at the ChangesetId. Then saving the maximum ChangesetId to the variable "maxId".

(4) At the end, BuildDetails.SourceGetVersion = "C" + maxId.ToString(). The "C" indicates, that the version is a changeset.

I hope someone finds this piece of "Code" useful!

Christian

Comment: Awesome solution (and yes this is an extraneous comment, but the solution warrants it...)

Comment: Great explanation of the problem and good solutions, although they will work only for builds of the latest code. They won't work for Gated Check-In builds or for custom builds, where version being built is not the latest.

Comment: I have implemented this very Workflow and have it working. I did make a modification, I could'nt assign to "BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion" in step (4) so I ended up introducing a string variable within the scope I needed.