# wants to get changeset number from specific branch in tfs not from project level

Tags: tfs

I am trying to get change-set number using "Source Version" TFS variable on TFS 2015 xaml build template. I am getting change set number but i am getting from project level. I don't want it from project level. I want Change set number from specific branch for specific solution. I am sure there is a way to do this but not sure that i need to make a change in Build template or Build definition?

Even my TFS build is showing wrong change set number. It's not showing the latest Chang set number from that specific solution which i am building. it's showing the change set number of team project as i mentioned above. That same change set i am getting from "Source Version" TFS variable.

can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this before at work, I did it as a series of Custom Code Activities in the XAML build. This isn't a trivial process if you have not done it before, but luckily [Ewald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422565/ewald-hofman) has done the hard work [documenting it](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx) all.

The first step is to get the Branch from the workspace mappings - I use the TFS API to walk up the hierarchy for the Folders in the Workspace mappings until I find a [Branch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.server.item.isbranch%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I have this as one activity where I pass in the Source Mappings and return the branch name.

Now I have the name of the branch, I can use the API again to perform a Query History and get the latest changeset ID for that branch.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also found another thread in stack overflow and followed it. (.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322728/tfs2010-wrong-changeset-appearing-at-sourcegetversion ) but i am stuck with one error. not able to find exactly from where this error is coming and what does it mean.!! Exception Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item (type ArgumentNullException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.TFCommonUtil.CheckStringForNullOrEmpty(String stringVar, String stringVarName, Boolean trim)